# Bulk export of an SSRS report and include parameter in the file name

Tags: reporting-services

I have an SSRS report that takes a person as a parameter, then generates a report for that person.  I want to run the report for a list of people, and I want to end up with one file per person, with their name in the file name.

For example, if I ran this report for Bill, Sue, and John, I'd like to see output like this:

```
Report-Bill.pdf
Report-Sue.pdf
Report-John.pdf
```

Is that possible within SSRS, or via an API?

Comment: The only out-of-the-box way of doing this is using data-driven subscriptions as far as I know. I have done something similar in Excel of all things via a bit of VBA (Excel was used as a list of parameters for each report). I'll dig out the code if that sounds of interest to oyu.

Comment: @AlanSchofield, thank you for the response.  I'm surprised that SSRS doesn't support this in a straightforward way.  If you do have that VBA code, I might be able to use it.  Thanks for the response!

Comment: I'll dig out the xlsm file and share a link to it tomorrow (10:15pm here now).